# derived class calls wrong base class constructor

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, constructor

Can you explain the output of the following code? And what do I need to do to call the right base class constructor?

Thanks.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <class CONTAINER> class SequenceComposite {
protected:
    CONTAINER m_data;
public:
    typedef typename CONTAINER::value_type value_type;
    typedef typename CONTAINER::allocator_type allocator_type;
    typedef typename CONTAINER::size_type size_type;
    explicit SequenceComposite(const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type()) : m_data(alloc) {
        std::cout << std::endl << "SequenceComposite(alloc)" << std::endl;
    }
    explicit SequenceComposite(size_type n, const value_type& val = value_type(),
        const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type()) : m_data(n, val, alloc) {
        std::cout << std::endl << "SequenceComposite(n, val, alloc)" << std::endl;
    }
    SequenceComposite(const SequenceComposite& x) : m_data(x.m_data) {
        std::cout << std::endl << "SequenceComposite(x)" << std::endl;
    }

};

template <class DTYPE>
class VectorComposite : public virtual SequenceComposite< std::vector<DTYPE> > {
public:
    typedef typename VectorComposite::value_type value_type;
    typedef typename VectorComposite::allocator_type allocator_type;
    typedef typename VectorComposite::size_type size_type;
    explicit VectorComposite(const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type()) : SequenceComposite< std::vector<DTYPE> >(alloc) {
        std::cout << "VectorComposite(alloc)" << std::endl;
    }
    explicit VectorComposite(size_type n, const value_type& val = value_type(),
        const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type()) : SequenceComposite< std::vector<DTYPE> >(n, val, alloc) {
        std::cout << "VectorComposite(n, val, alloc)" << std::endl;
    }
    VectorComposite(const VectorComposite& x) : SequenceComposite< std::vector<DTYPE> >(x) {
        std::cout << "VectorComposite(x)" << std::endl;
    }

};

template<typename T> class MyModel : public virtual VectorComposite<T> {
    public:
        MyModel() {
            std::cout << "MyModel()" << std::endl;
        };
        MyModel(const MyModel<T> &vec) : VectorComposite<T>(vec) {
            std::cout << "MyModel(x)" << std::endl;
        }
        MyModel( size_t n, const T& value= 0) : VectorComposite<T>(n, value) {
            std::cout << "MyModel(n, val)" << std::endl;
        }
};

int main() {
    MyModel<float> c(4, 2.0);
    MyModel<float> e(c);

    VectorComposite<float> a(3, 2.0);
    VectorComposite<float> b(c);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
SequenceComposite(alloc)
VectorComposite(n, val, alloc)
MyModel(n, val)

SequenceComposite(alloc)
VectorComposite(x)
MyModel(x)

SequenceComposite(n, val, alloc)
VectorComposite(n, val, alloc)

SequenceComposite(x)
VectorComposite(x)
```

I expected

```
SequenceComposite(n, val, alloc)
VectorComposite(n, val, alloc)
MyModel(n, val)

SequenceComposite(x)
VectorComposite(x)
MyModel(x)
...
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126522/c-virtual-inheritance

Comment: Why do you even use `virtual` inheritance?

Comment: @PeterWood: While I agree that the expected result should be explicitly spelled out, it's not difficult to see that e.g. in the first case it seems that the "wrong" `SequenceComposite` constructor is called.

Comment: @Jon We all have different ways of replying. I want to improve the question, not necessarily to answer it.

Comment: @Grizzly Because of http://stackoverflow.com/a/11954411/861164. James Kanze suggested "Note the virtual inheritance. This should generally be the default when you're extending interfaces." I want to exapnd the interface

Comment: @Michael: You don't expand **an** interface in the typical sense, since you base class has member variables (and maybe even non pure virtual member functions?). An interface in the typical sense is a base class which only describes the interface (well obviously) without containing any implementation details. In that case `virtual` inheritance is useful to avoid the [diamond inheritance problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem). Unless your class risks running into that problem there is little reason to use `virtual` inheritance

Comment: @CharlesBailey If the constructor of `VectorComposite` doesn't do anything itself could I just omit its call and only call the constructor of `SequenceComposite`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtual base classes are initialized from the constructor of the **most derived** type. So in the first two examples, the default constructor for `SequenceComposite` is called. That's the one that takes an `allocator_type` with a default argument. To use a different constructor, call it from the initializer list of the most derived type.